# Laravel 5 binding other object to contracts

Tags: laravel-5

I started using Laravel 5 and tried to learn things about contracts but i still have some questions about them.

For example I want to alter the Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker contract (used in App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController )

The contract is an Interface but somehow Laravel knows what implementation belongs to that contract..

I want to change the implementation to my custom one.

But what is the correct way of loading my custom PasswordBroker class?

1. Should i bind my custom class in the AppServiceProvider?

   ```
       $this->app->bind(
       'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker',
       'App\Services\MyPasswordBroker'
   );
   ```

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question ;)

But yes I would probably change the binding in the AppServiceProvider as you suggested yourself :)

Comment: Have a look at my answer. Let me know if there's further questions : )

Answer (score 2):

## Where does Laravel itself bind the default implementations?

It's in ['Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php'](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L1041)

```
'auth.password'        => ['Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker'],
```

## Can I just overwrite the default bindings?

According to the [official documentations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/extending#container-based-extension): Yes.

> You can easily extend and override this class within your own application by overriding this binding.

But remember to replace the original service provider in the config/app.php

> Note that this class extends the HashServiceProvider, not the default ServiceProvider base class. Once you have extended the service provider, swap out the HashServiceProvider in your config/app.php configuration file with the name of your extended provider.

## Your case

So, in your case, you need to extend the 'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider' to remain other things happened in the service provider.

Take a look at the [default service provider](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordResetServiceProvider.php).

Let me know if you have other questions.